# React: Warning: validateDOMNesting(...): Text nodes cannot appear as a child of <tbody>

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I'm trying to fill table from data in React, however I am getting an above mentioned error.

this is the function which fills the table:

```
let numberOfColumns = props.tabColumns.split(",").length;
let tableData = props.tabRows.split(",");

function generateRows(){
  let r = ``;
  for (let i=0; i<tableData.length/numberOfColumns; i++){
    r =`${r}<tr>`;
    for(let j=0; j<numberOfColumns; j++){
      r = `${r}<td>${tableData[i*numberOfColumns+j]}</td>`;
    }
    r =`${r}</tr>`;
  }
  console.log(r);
  return r;
}
```

This is the table:

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      {props.tabColumns.split(",").map((column, index) => <th key={"column"+index}>{column}</th>)}
    </tr>
    {generateRows()}
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Data:

```
tabColumns: "Name,Age,Occupation",
tabRows: "John,18,Student," +
  "Miranda,23,Nurse," +
  "Ashley,32,Telephonist," +
  "Rose,28,Driver"
```

Result looks like this:
[image: result]
Problem is somewhere in the generateRows function. What could be the culprit? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have r being like the entire row, but then prepend it to a TD? r =`${r}<tr>`; It's never reset inside that loop so...

Comment: generateRows is currently returning a string. It needs to return JSX (probably an array of JSX elements in this case).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't mix React rendering with manual html construction unless you really really need to.  It eliminates the benefits of using React in the first place.  Render your rows using React!

```
function renderRow(tableData, numberOfColumns, i) {
  const cells = [];
  for (const j = 0; j < numberOfColumns; ++j) {
    cells.push(<td>tableData[i*numberOfColumns+j]</td>);
  }

  return <tr>{cells}</tr>;
}

render() {
  const rows = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < tableData.length / numberOfColumns; ++i) {
    rows.push(renderRow(tableData, numberOfColumns, i);
  }

  return (
    <table>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          {props.tabColumns.split(",").map((column, index) => <th key={"column"+index}>{column}</th>)}
        </tr>
        {rows}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  );
}
```

Comment: Could you be please able to help?
`<tbody>
        {!props?.data?.length && (
            <tr>
              <td colSpan={props.noDataColSpan} className={props.noDataClass}>
                No Data Found
              </td>
            </tr>
          )}
          {props?.data?.length &&
            props.data.map((row: any, index: number) => (
              <tr key={index}>
                {row.map((rowData: string, idx: number) => (
                  <td key={idx}>{setRowData(rowData, idx, index)}</td>
                ))}
              </tr>
            ))}
        </tbody>`

Answer (score 0):

As people mentioned, generateRows is returning a string. To get what I needed I had to pass this string to a parser (https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-react-parser) which gave me the correct output.